Trouble with AJAX POST Request Redirecting to /login Path Instead of Route in Laravel 10
Im attempting to send a POST request to one of my routes defined in api.php within my Laravel application. Here are the relevant route definitions:
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function(){
    Route::post('/image-recognition', [DashboardController::class, 'imageRecognize'])->name('image-recognition');
    Route::post('/bolt-size/change', [DashboardController::class,'boltSizeQtyChange'])->name('bolt-size-qty-change');
    Route::post('/register-submit', [RegisterController::class, 'register'])->name('register-submit');
})


And this is the JavaScript code for my AJAX request using blade templating engine:
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', url, true);

xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", 'XMLHttpRequest');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", 'multipart/form-data'); // or application/json
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token","{{ csrf_token() }}");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-UID","{{auth()->user()->id}}");

xhr.onload = function() {
    // onload code here
};

xhr.onerror = function() {
    console.error('Network error occurred');
};

// Convert the input value to JSON format
var data = JSON.stringify(requestData);
xhr.send(data);

My AJAX POST request is being redirected to the /login path, presumably due to lacking the required user authentication. However, upon inspecting the developer tools, I noticed that the request includes both XCSRF-TOKEN and laravel_session. How can I ensure that my request contains the necessary authentication credentials that can pass the auth middleware? Am I missing something here?

Please kindly don't close my question if you need more details, i'll edit my question and add those details you need

I've solved it, might explain it on this question after I do some research, thanks

Your question is vague, but keep these points in mind:
You can't use session in api paths, but you can in web.
Does your ajax request go through after you have authenticated?
If yes, then the problem may be due to the definition of the paths in the api, because as I said, you cannot use the session in the api, so transfer the paths to web.php
